# Characters determine exactly representations in 4 dimensions?

Tags: representation-theory, characters

This is an exercise in the second chapter of Fulton & Harris's 'Representation theory - A first course' Book ;

"Show that if we know the character $X_V$ of a representation $V$, then we know the eigenvalues of each element $g$ of $G$, in the sense that we know the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $g:V \rightarrow V$. Carry this out explicitly for elements $g\in G$ of orders $2, 3$, and $4$, and for a representation of $G$ on a vector space of dimension $2, 3$, or $4$ ."

This is a computational challenge.

So we can work out $dim V=2$ and $dim V=3$ , I am a little stuck for $dim V=4$ , in this case the characteristic polynomial is $$P(\lambda)= \lambda^4 - X_V(g)\lambda^3+ a_2\lambda^2- a_3\lambda + det(A_g)$$
where $a_2= \sum_{i<j}^4\ \lambda_i\lambda_j$ (all the 2-terms) 
and $a_3= \sum_{i<j<k}^4\ \lambda_i\lambda_j\lambda_k$ (all the 3-terms) , where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4$ being the eigenvalues of $g$ 
Also $det(A_g)= \lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\lambda_4$

We need to compute these $3$ coefficients for elements of order $2, 3$ and $4$

- For elements of order $2$ : using $g^2=e$ and $g= g^{-1}$ we can have 
  $a_2= \frac{X_V(g)^2-4}{2}$ and $a_3= det(A_g)X_V(g)$ and $det(A_g)=\pm 1$ 
  So here is there a way to know whether $det(A_g)= 1$ or $-1$ ?
- For elements of order $3$: using $g^3=e$ and $g^2= g^{-1}$ we can have 
  $$a_2= \frac{X_V(g)^2}{2}- \frac{a_3}{2\ det(A_g)}$$ and $$ \left(6+ 3\frac{X_V(g)}{det(A_g)}\right)a_3= 8+ X_V(g)^3$$
  Also of course $det(A_g)=e^{ik\frac{2\pi}{3}}$ for some $k\in \{0,1,2\}$
  So is there a way to know $det(A_g)$ ? 
  Also we need $X_V(g)\neq -2\ det(A_g)$ for the second formula to give $a_3$

You can imagine how this will be for elements of order $4$ ! I must be missing some clue to make the computations easier ? ...

Comment: Hint for elements of order two: If $g^2=1$ then every eigenvalue $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4\in\{+1,-1\}$ and you know their sum. Can you tell how many of them are $+1$ and how many are $-1$?

Comment: A further hint. If $g$ has order four, you will need both $\chi_V(g)$ and $\chi_V(g^2)$ to distinguish between certain cases.

Comment: Ok I like that first hint, with the second one we can use $g^2$ which has order 2

Comment: I just corrected $X_V(g)$ can be zero also, but still for elements of order 2 all the 4 cases (one of the $\lambda_i$ , two of them, three, or all of them are $-1$ ) are possible, are you saying we should eliminate some of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\dim V=4$. Assume that $\chi_V$ is known as a function $G\to\Bbb{C}$. Assume that $\operatorname{ord}_G(g)=m$. The eigenvalues are roots of unity, satisfying the equation $\lambda^m=1$. We use the character values to determine the multiplicity of each solution as an eigenvalue.

**Case $m=2$.**
The eigenvalues of $g$ are roots of unity of order two. That is, $\lambda_j\in\{+1,-1\}$
for $j=1,2,3,4$. If $+1$ occurs $k$ times, then $-1$ occurs $4-k$ times, and the characteristic polynomial is
$$P(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)^k(\lambda+1)^{4-k}.$$
The point is that we can solve for $k$ because we know
$$\chi_V(g)=k\cdot1+(4-k)\cdot(-1)=2k-4.$$
Therefore the following table exhausts all the possibilities:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\chi_V(g)&P(\lambda)\\
\hline
4&(\lambda-1)^4\\
2&(\lambda-1)^3(\lambda+1)\\
0&(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+1)^2\\
-2&(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)^3\\
-4&(\lambda+1)^4
\end{array}
$$

**Case $m=4$.** This time the eigenvalues of $g$ are in the set $\{+1,i,-1,-i\}$.
If $+1$ occurs $a$ times, $i$ with multiplicity $b$, $-1$ with multiplicity $c$ and $-i$ with multiplicity $d$, then we know that $a+b+c+d=4$ and that
$$\chi_V(g)=(a-c)+(b-d)i.$$
This time the known value of $\chi_V(g)$ won't determine the numbers $a,b,c,d$ uniquely. But, given the above, we can deduce that $g^2$ has $+1$ as an eigenvalue with multiplicity $a+c$ and $-1$ with multiplicity $b+d$. As in the first case, knowing $\chi_V(g^2)$ hence tells us what $a+c$ and $b+d$ are. The real (resp. imaginary) part of $\chi_V(g)$ tells us the values of $a-c$ (resp. $c-d$). Of course, when we know all of $a+c,a-c, b+d$ and $b-d$ we can solve for all four multiplicities.

In other words, only when the absolute values of the real and imaginary parts of $\chi_V(g)$ add up to $4=\dim V$ can we read the multiplicities of the eigenvalues from $\chi_V(g)$ alone. If some pairs of eigenvalues cancel each other (either $i-i=0$ or $1-1=0$), then we need help from $\chi_V(g^2)$ as it tells us the number of real (resp. purely imaginary) eigenvalues.

For example $\chi_V(g)=1+i$ may come from either $1+1-1+i$ or $1+i+i-i$. In those two cases we have $\chi_V(g^2)=1+1+1-1=2$ or $1-1-1-1=-2$. So knowing $\chi_V(g^2)$ tells us which kind of a cancellation took place.

The number of cases is higher, and the table is a bit longer.
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\chi_V(g^2)&\chi_V(g)&P(\lambda)\\
\hline
4&4&(\lambda-1)^4\\
4&2&(\lambda-1)^3(\lambda+1)\\
4&0&(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+1)^2\\
4&-2&(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)^3\\
4&-4&(\lambda+1)^4\\
2&3+i&(\lambda-1)^3(\lambda-i)\\
2&3-i&(\lambda-1)^3(\lambda+i)\\
2&1+i&(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+1)(\lambda-i)\\
2&1-i&(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+1)(\lambda+i)\\
2&-1+i&(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)^2(\lambda-i)\\
2&-1-i&(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)^2(\lambda+i)\\
2&-3+i&(\lambda+1)^3(\lambda-i)\\
2&-3-i&(\lambda+1)^3(\lambda+i)\\
0&2+2i&(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda-i)^2\\
0&2&(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda-i)(\lambda+i)\\
0&2-2i&(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+i)^2\\
0&2i&(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)(\lambda-i)^2\\
0&0&(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)(\lambda-i)(\lambda+i)\\
0&-2i&(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)(\lambda+i)^2\\
0&-2+2i&(\lambda+1)^2(\lambda-i)^2\\
0&-2&(\lambda+1)^2(\lambda-i)(\lambda+i)\\
0&-2-2i&(\lambda+1)^2(\lambda+i)^2\\
-2&1+3i&(\lambda-1)(\lambda-i)^3\\
-2&1+i&(\lambda-1)(\lambda-i)^2(\lambda+i)\\
-2&1-i&(\lambda-1)(\lambda-i)(\lambda+i)^2\\
-2&1-3i&(\lambda-1)(\lambda+i)^3\\
-2&-1+3i&(\lambda+1)(\lambda-i)^3\\
-2&-1+i&(\lambda+1)(\lambda-i)^2(\lambda+i)\\
-2&-1-i&(\lambda+1)(\lambda-i)(\lambda+i)^2\\
-2&-1-3i&(\lambda+1)(\lambda+i)^3\\
-4&4i&(\lambda-i)^4\\
-4&2i&(\lambda-i)^3(\lambda+i)\\
-4&0&(\lambda-i)^2(\lambda+i)^2\\
-4&-2i&(\lambda-i)(\lambda+i)^3\\
-4&-4i&(\lambda+i)^4
\end{array}
$$